# UITableViewCell порядок с низу на верх

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview, tableview

**Здравствуйте!**

Проблема такова: В TableView содержится короткий массив indexPath.row, когда выполняется скролинг вниз, данные с него очищаются, и записываются новые, а именно уникальный номер ячейки, и моя функция которая скролит в низ до якобы последней ячейки - в пролете, потому-что скролит к последнему номеру indexPath.row, который как мы знаем хранит не все номера, а это значит что это не совсем последняя ячейка.

Вопрос: Как исправить эту проблему? Чтобы скролил именно к последней ячейке.

Comment: все должно работать нормально. покажите код

Comment: scrollToRowAtIndexPath выполняется если туда брейкпоинт поставить?

Comment: Да, он то скролит. Только вот опускает именно к той, которая отобразилась на экране. Не хочет сразу скролить к самой последней ячейке, ибо часть indexPath куда-то пропала, а полностью её получить -- немного скролить в низ.

Comment: так и ставьте, что вы хотите скроллить к последней: вместо indexPath.row создайте indexPath указывающий на нижнюю и туда скроллите. `NSIndexPath *path = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:msgArrayToken.count-1 inSection:0];`

Comment: Спасибо. Это идеальное решение. Хотя сам до этого не допер, нужно было немного вдуматься. Спешка к добру не приводит(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

так и ставьте, что вы хотите скроллить к последней: вместо indexPath.row создайте indexPath указывающий на нижнюю и туда скроллите. `NSIndexPath *path = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:msgArrayToken.count-1 inSection:0];`